# Как узнать какие элементы лежат в выборке jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как узнать какие html элементы лежат в выборке jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.each() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. А также:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {
    console.log($elements[i]); // дом-элемент
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Открываем консоль разработчика (в Chrome это **Ctrl+Shift+J**, например) и пишем там вывод селектора в консоль:

```
console.log( $('.myClass') );
```